# Magento 1.9.1 CE display items as sold, not out of stock on frontend

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, out-of-stock

Magento Experts, we're an [online pawn shop](https://shop.pawnbahn.com) and currently don't stock retail inventory in volume.  What I mean by this is that we obtain items to be put out for sale either by purchasing the item or the single item becoming inventory due to a pawn loan forfeiture.

We would like to display an item that has been sold on cart pages as "SOLD", not "Out of Stock".  `Is there a simple way of doing this?  Your help is greatly appreciated.`

Comment: when a item become sold  at cart page

Comment: I think you have to replace out of stock with sold in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change the text, you could just edit the app/locale/your_locale_here/Mage_Catalog.csv and find "Out of Stock" text there and change the translation (the latter) part of it to "SOLD".

Of course that is shown also when the product is not sold at all but just out of stock.

Comment: That's a useful work-around.  Thanks @webninja.